# VS online build stuck on license compiler (LC.exe) for ActiPro WPF Controls

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, azure-devops, licenses.licx

Visual Studio online build stuck on license compiler for Actipro WPF controls.We are using hosted controller.We had purchased Actipro and had included the license(License.licx) for the same in the solution.Please find the log below

> 2017-09-12T14:16:58.2258924Z   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools\LC.exe /target:Application.exe
>   /complist:Properties\Licenses.licx /outdir:obj\Release\
>   /i:d:\a\1\s\Application\Main\Application\ActiproAssemblies\v16.1.0636\ActiproSoftware.Charts.Wpf.dll
>   /i:d:\a\1\s\Application\Main\Application\ActiproAssemblies\v16.1.0636\ActiproSoftware.DataGrid.Contrib.Wpf.dll
>   /i:d:\a\1\s\Application\Main\Application\ActiproAssemblies\v16.1.0636\ActiproSoftware.Docking.Wpf.dll
>   /i:d:\a\1\s\Application\Main\Application\ActiproAssemblies\v16.1.0636\ActiproSoftware.Editors.Interop.DataGrid.Wpf.dll
>   /i:d:\a\1\s\Application\Main\Application\ActiproAssemblies\v16.1.0636\ActiproSoftware.Editors.Interop.PropertyGrid.Wpf.dll
>   /i:d:\a\1\s\Application\Main\Application\ActiproAssemblies\v16.1.0636\ActiproSoftware.Editors.Interop.Ribbon.Wpf.dll
>   /i:d:\a\1\s\Application\Main\Application\ActiproAssemblies\v16.1.0636\ActiproSoftware.Editors.Wpf.dll
>   /i:d:\a\1\s\Application\Main\Application\ActiproAssemblies\v16.1.0636\ActiproSoftware.Gauge.Wpf.dll
>   /i:d:\a\1\s\Application\Main\Application\ActiproAssemblies\v16.1.0636\ActiproSoftware.PropertyGrid.Interop.WinForms.Wpf.dll
>   /i:d:\a\1\s\Application\Main\Application\ActiproAssemblies\v16.1.0636\ActiproSoftware.PropertyGrid.Wpf.dll
>   /i:d:\a\1\s\Application\Main\Application\ActiproAssemblies\v16.1.0636\ActiproSoftware.Ribbon.Wpf.dll
>   /i:d:\a\1\s\Application\Main\Application\ActiproAssemblies\v16.1.0636\ActiproSoftware.Shared.Wpf.dll
>   /i:d:\a\1\s\Application\Main\Application\ActiproAssemblies\v16.1.0636\ActiproSoftware.SyntaxEditor.Wpf.dll
>   /i:d:\a\1\s\Application\Main\Application\ActiproAssemblies\v16.1.0636\ActiproSoftware.Text.Wpf.dll
>   /i:d:\a\1\s\Application\Main\Application\ActiproAssemblies\v16.1.0636\ActiproSoftware.Themes.Luna.Wpf.dll
>   /i:d:\a\1\s\Application\Main\Application\ActiproAssemblies\v16.1.0636\ActiproSoftware.Themes.Office.Wpf.dll
>   2017-09-12T14:45:54.6694381Z Attempting to cancel the build...
>   2017-09-12T14:45:54.6764555Z Done Building Project
>   "d:\a\1\s\Application\Main\Application\Application.sln" (default
>   targets) -- FAILED. 2017-09-12T14:45:54.6774406Z ##[warning]C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2829,5):
>   Warning MSB5021: "lc" and its child processes are being terminated in
>   order to cancel the build. 2017-09-12T14:45:54.6774406Z C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2829,5):
>   warning MSB5021: "lc" and its child processes are being terminated in
>   order to cancel the build.
>   [d:\a\1\s\Application\Main\Application\Application.UI\Application.UI.csproj]
>   2017-09-12T14:45:54.6784347Z Done Building Project
>   "d:\a\1\s\Application\Main\Application\ApplicationSetup\ApplicationSetup.wixproj"
>   (default targets) -- FAILED. 2017-09-12T14:45:54.6826686Z Done
>   Building Project
>   "d:\a\1\s\Application\Main\Application\Application.UI\Application.UI.csproj"
>   (default targets) -- FAILED. 2017-09-12T14:45:54.6826686Z 
>   2017-09-12T14:45:54.6826686Z Build FAILED.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Actipro on the build server, so you need to setup a private build agent (You can’t install it on Hosted agent).

[Deploy an agent on Windows.](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows)

Some threads: [Licensing on Build Machines](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/community/thread/21445/licensing-on-build-machines); [Version Control and Actipro license files](http://actipro-website.azurewebsites.net/community/thread/5561/version-control-and-actipro-license-files)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to install the [EmptyLicensesLicx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EmptyLicensesLicx/) nuget package on your project, and it will generate an empty `Licenses.licx` in your project, before it gets compiled (which should be all you need for the build to work).